# How to implement cancellable worker thread

Tags: multithreading, .net-4.0, backgroundworker

I'm trying to implement a cancellable worker thread using the new threading constructs in System.Threading.Tasks namespace.
So far I have have come up with this implementation:

```
public sealed class Scheduler
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;
    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task Worker { get; private set; }

    public void Start()
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        Worker = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () => RunTasks(_cancellationTokenSource.Token),
             _cancellationTokenSource.Token
        );
    }

    private static void RunTasks(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000); // simulate work
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        try
        {
            _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            Worker.Wait(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            // OperationCanceledException is expected when a Task is cancelled.
        }
    }
}
```

When `Stop()` returns I expect `Worker.Status` to be `TaskStatus.Canceled`.
My unit tests have shown that under certain conditions `Worker.Status` remains set to `TaskStatus.Running`.

**Is this a correct way to implement a cancellable worker thread?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the problem is in your call to

```
Worker.Wait(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

That's waiting for the *token* to be signalled - which it already is, because you've just called `Cancel()`. If you change that to just

```
Worker.Wait();
```

then I believe you'll see a state of `RanToCompletion`. You won't see Canceled, because your task isn't throwing `OperationCanceledException`. If you change your `RunTasks` method to call

```
cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
```

at the end, then you'll need to catch an `AggregateException` in `Stop` - but then you'll see a state of `Canceled` at the end.

At least, that's what my experimentation shows :)